# add associative arrays with different keys to main associative array

Tags: php, laravel

Have problem with associative array.

I have code:

```
$array[]=[$key=>['value'=>$value,'value1'=>$value1'];
```

$key value can be repeated, it means that for $key = 4 we can have few options of $value and $value1.

It generates structure as following:

```
[0]=>[4=>['value'=>$value,'value1'=>$value1'];
[1]=>[4=>['value'=>$value,'value1'=>$value1'];
[2]=>[4=>['value'=>$value,'value1'=>$value1'];
```

The think is that i want to achieve different structure:

```
[4]=>[0=>['value'=>$value,'value1'=>$value1'];
     [1 =>['value'=>$value,'value1'=>$value1'];
     [2 =>['value'=>$value,'value1'=>$value1'];
```

laravel dd should show it that way:

```
^ array:1 [▼
  4 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▶]
    1 => array:2 [▶]
    2 => array:2 [▶]
  ]
]
```

Inside array with key 4 i want to put few arrays with keys as following 0,1,2 etc.

I tried like so:

```
$array[$key]=[['value'=>$value,'value1'=>$value1']];
```

but its overriding inside array key, and any time its = 0 like here:

```
[4]=>[0=>['value'=>$value,'value1'=>$value1'];
```

laravel:

```
array:1 [▼
  4 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▶]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What a shame just after post I get an idea.

```
$array[$key][]=['value'=>$value,'value1'=>$value1'];
```

That what I was looking for.